# I can't use a dotenv db details file to connect to mysql using python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, .env

I'm trying to connect to my localhost mysql db with Python, using a .env file for my DB details.

This is my db.py file to connect to my db

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import mysql.connector

# Load the .env file
load_dotenv()

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host=os.getenv("DATABASE_HOST"),
    user=os.getenv("DATABASE_USER"),
    password=os.getenv("DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
    database=os.getenv("DATABASE_NAME")
)


cursor = mydb.cursor()
cursor.execute("select @@version")
version = cursor.fetchone()

if version:
    print('Running version: ', version)
else:
    print('Not connected.')
```

This is my .env file with the DB details

```
DATABASE_USER:***
DATABASE_PASSWORD:***
DATABASE_HOST:localhost
DATABASE_NAME:***
```

It doesn't want to work at all. I receive an error from one of my modules
 `Extension '***' raised an error: DatabaseError: 2017 (HY000): Can't open named pipe to host: .  pipe: MySQL (2)`

If I use my DB details right in my db.py file, it works just fine.

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
     host='localhost',
     user='***',
     password='***',
     database='***'
)
```

What am I doing wrong? I spent the last 2 days to figure out a solution, but to no avail.

Comment: Solved. I used : instead of = in the .env file. fml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I used `:` instead of `=` in the .env file.

Here is the correct .env file:

```
DATABASE_USER=***
DATABASE_PASSWORD=***
DATABASE_HOST=localhost
DATABASE_NAME=***
```